# how to use Tizen sdk to develop apps

Tags: android, wear-os, tizen, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am new to android apps development.Shall I develop android apps for Samsung gear devices? How to convert android apps to samsung gear using tizen sdk?please help me to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tizen SDK contains a few similar tools as the Android SDK. If you're happy with adb, sdb will feel very similar.

Programming-wise, Tizen is very different. You either write applications in "Web" mode, i.e. HTML-5, or in "native" mode, i.e. C/C++.  No Java.